# How to write a DB2 Function with a Timestamp as input parameter

Tags: sql, db2

I try to write a function with an input like `( IN myDate DateTime)` but i run into `"DATETIME" ist ein nicht definierter Name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=3.69.56`

How can i fix it?

Comment: `DATETIME` is not a built-in data-type in Db2. Use `DATE`, `TIME` or `TIMESTAMP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `TIMESTAMP` input parameter, you should declare it as such. See an example:

```
$ db2 "create or replace procedure timestamp_to_month(in ts timestamp)
    language sql
    return month(date(ts))"

$ db2 "call timestamp_to_month(current timestamp)" 

  Return Status = 9
$ db2 "call timestamp_to_month(timestamp('2019-01-01'))" 

  Return Status = 1
```